# Missing access to cross-repo policies or project-wide branch policies in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops

After the latest update including the cross-repo policies in the Azure DevOps portal, I can't add project-wide branch protections even though I am the Organization and Project owner.

Is there any special permissions that is required to be assigned to my user?

Thanks,
Ví

---

**Solution:**

```
Leave all security groups except "Project Administrators"
```

Comment: Do you see the "Cross-repo policies" menu item on the left pane of the project settings? If not, perhaps the feature hasn't yet rolled out to your location? The docs say: "*These features will roll out over the next two to three weeks.*" It's published November 4th. Technically, three weeks have not passed yet :-)

Comment: Yes, I do see the Cross-repo policies feature however I cannot add a branch protection since it's grey out and it states: Yo do not have permission to edict project-wide branch policies. I guess it's because somehow I am missing some permission.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any special permissions that is required to be assigned to my user?

You should check your user's access level, if they are **Stakeholder** levels, then they will not have the permissions to add project-wide branch protections.

If set my user as Stakeholder levels on the Organization Settings->Users:

[image]

Then, my user will get the states: Yo do not have permission to edict project-wide branch policies:

[image]

So, to resolve this issue, you should to assign a higher access level to your users, like **Basic**.

Hope this helps.

Comment: My access level is Visual Studio Enterprise subscription, I guess this should provide me higher access level such as this one.

Comment: @ViMan, Yes, valid Visual Studio Enterprise subscription has all features of Basic. So, please check if your subscription expires? And I test a account with Visual Studio Enterprise subscription, it also works fine. As test, you could add another test account with Basic level, check if it works fine.

Comment: @ViMan Haven't heard from you for a while. Did you check if your subscription is expired. How is it going?

Comment: I have realized the problem was related with a user belonging to different groups with different access level. E.g: An organization administrator belonging to the contributor group it will keep the most restrictive access level based in a least privilege philosophy.

Comment: Okay, my solution was to leave all groups, but the "Project Administrator" solved it.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the Problem by leaving all groups, except the "Project Administrators" group.

This was based on @ViMans comment.

Quote:

> I have realized the problem was related with a user belonging to
>   different groups with different access level. E.g: An organization
>   administrator belonging to the contributor group it will keep the most
>   restrictive access level based in a least privilege philosophy